# SQL mariadb doesn't return fulltext search results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, full-text-search

I have table products with structure:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `request` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` enum('kg','pc') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type_of_sale` enum('retail','wholesale') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'retail',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `products_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `products_title_index` (`title`);
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_index` (`title`,`description`);

ALTER TABLE `products`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

When I search with query on then table products:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('Hatter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Then get **32** results but when I tried with this query template word `atter`, `att` or `ter` doesn't get any results. How I can get results correctly or maybe I've error in my query?

**MariaDB** version: **10.3.22**

Comment: Why would searching for those terms return anything with "hatter"?  Do you understand that full text compares *words* (in boolean mode)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want `like`:

```
where title like '%atter%' or
      description like '%atter%'
```

`MATCH()` is not equivalent to `LIKE`.  They do different things and for text searches, `MATCH()` is often closer to what users actually need.  There are many cases where people start by using `LIKE` and then realize that `MATCH()` is a better fit.  This sounds like this opposite circumstance.

However, if you need wildcard searching for arbitrary substrings in text, then `LIKE` or `REGEXP` may be what you really need.  Of course, the issue in that case is performance.

Comment: I tried example [from this post](https://arianacosta.com/php/laravel/tutorial-full-text-search-laravel-5/) and in my case doesn't work search by fulltext columns index.

Comment: With `MATCH()` I can't search substrings in text using created fulltext index? @GordonLinoff

Comment: To search substrings if I must use `LIKE` then I not need for `FULTEXT` index column in my table?

Comment: @AndreasHunter . . . `MATCH()` is quite well documented.  You can search when the "prefix" is the same, but not arbitrary substrings (so, "HATT" but not "ATT").